# Prevent copied url redirect to /

Tags: react-router-dom, react-admin

When we copied an url to our browser like `localhost:3000/#/mypage` we are redirect to the homepage `/`.

When I look at the demo of react-admin the copy/paste for `/page` already work. So I wonder what I miss ?

I tried to catch the url paste in the `login` page with `useHistory()` and `useLocation()`from `react-router-dom` but they only catch the `/login` and the redirect to `/`.

I can catch the url with `window.location` on the `App` component but it's automaticaly rewrite by something else (first `console.log()` show the right path, second show nothing for the same component).

So where can I catch the url copied ?

Comment: In a Single Page Application, the contents of the address bar and the contents of the page may not be related in any way.
What do you want to do?

Comment: I should precise that I use react-admin and the case is already handle normally, but in my case it not work.